# Selecting multiple columns to plot with plotly python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, plotly-python

I have the following code:

```
def campaign_plot(col1,col2):
    grouper = df.groupby(['Day','Campaign']).agg({col1: 'sum', col2: 'mean'}).unstack()
    result = grouper.fillna(0)
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = result.index,
    y = result.iloc[:, [0, 4]],  #<---
    name = '1',
    line = dict(
        color = ('rgb(205, 12, 24)'),
        width = 2)
    ))

    fig.show()
```

I want to create a plot using the first and fifth columns of a dataframe. If i just do `result.iloc[:, [0, 4]]` this outputs the correct columns of the dataframe. But in the plot it just outputs two points. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Here is a snippet of the dataframe, which is grouped:

```
    Day          Campaign Clicks    CTR
0   2013-08-05   1        0         0
1   2013-08-05   3        1         0.5
2   2013-08-05   7        0         0.2
3   2013-08-05   15       5         3
4   2013-08-08   1        6         0.1
5   2013-08-08   3        1         0
6   2013-08-08   7        15        4.5
7   2013-08-08   15       0         1
8   2013-08-10   1        6         2.2
9   2013-08-10   3        20        0
10  2013-08-10   7        1         0.2
11  2013-08-10   15       1         0.1
```

So in the function, col1 is Clicks and col2 is CTR. Clicks is summed while CTR is averaged.

The above dataframe is then grouped by Campaign and by Day, so that in the graph the x axis is the day and each Campaign has a separate line.

Comment: Post the original data instead, df, because you have indexed data that makes it hard to replicate the example.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes OK did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to melt you dataframe. Here is an example of how you could do this.Suppose that you have the following dataframe:

```
          Date       High        Low       Open      Close     Volume  \
0   2019-01-02  19.000000  17.980000  18.010000  18.830000   87148700   
1   2019-01-03  18.680000  16.940001  18.420000  17.049999  117277600   
2   2019-01-04  19.070000  17.430000  17.549999  19.000000  111878600   
3   2019-01-07  20.680000  19.000000  19.440001  20.570000  107157000   
4   2019-01-08  21.200001  19.680000  21.190001  20.750000  121271000   
..         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...   
458 2020-10-26  84.970001  80.860001  82.550003  82.230003   69423700   
459 2020-10-27  82.370003  77.570000  82.000000  78.879997  156669500   
460 2020-10-28  78.959999  75.760002  78.730003  76.400002   76529900   
461 2020-10-29  79.180000  76.290001  76.750000  78.019997   52784100   
462 2020-10-30  77.699997  74.230003  77.089996  75.290001   51349000
```

and that you wish to plot column `High` and `Close`. Then, an easy way to do this would be:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df.plot(x='Date', y=[ 'High', 'Close'])
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='Date', value_vars=['High', 'Close'])
px.line(df_melt, x='Date' , y='value' , color='variable')
```

**EDIT: Adaptation of solution to the actual data**

The problem you are facing is the facts that that you have, after grouping, a multi-level indexing, which makes it hard to work with in this context. A work-around is to drop them. I am not an expert but I do this this way (usually). First, I want to drop the indexes in such a way that I will keep track of the columns (the name need to correspond to Clicks and CTR AND Campaign). I therefore need to make the Campaign number a string, then do the groupby that you did

```
df['Campaign'] = df['Campaign'].astype(str)
grouper = df.groupby(['Day','Campaign']).agg({'Clicks': 'sum', 'CTR': 'mean'}).unstack()
```

Now, comes the tricky part of reindexing (uggly but it works)

```
a = grouper.columns
ind = pd.Index([e[0] + e[1] for e in a.tolist()])
grouper.columns = ind
result = grouper.reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
         Day  Clicks1  Clicks15  Clicks3  Clicks7  CTR1  CTR15  CTR3  CTR7
0  2013-08-05        0         5        1        0   0.0    3.0   0.5   0.2
1  2013-08-08        6         0        1       15   0.1    1.0   0.0   4.5
2  2013-08-10        6         1       20        1   2.2    0.1   0.0   0.2
```

The last step is the plotting.

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
result.plot(x='Day', y=[ 'Clicks1', 'CTR1'])
result_melt = result.melt(id_vars='Day', value_vars= ['Clicks1', 'CTR1'])
px.line(result_melt, x='Day' , y='value' , color='variable')
```

In your function, you'll have to replace `['Clicks1', 'CTR1']` by `['col1', 'col2']`

which returns the following plot:

[image]

Comment: That is the outcome I want to achieve, but how do I adapt it for grouped data? In the dataframe, I want to first group by one column and then for that grouped data, plot the two lines for each group. Does that make sense? Is that possible?

Comment: Your grouped data is a dataframe like my df in the example. Identify the names of the columns in your result dataframe and do the same as I did. Alternatively, edit you question by posting say 10 lines of you result df and I'll adapt my code to your data.

Comment: I've added the dataframe, because groupby always confuses me